# What's the best practice to pass data between Activities? Should I favor Parceable over Serializable as Intent Extra?

Tags: android, serialization, android-intent

I'm developing an app which basically navigates through a xml-feed. When I parse the feed or let's say the list, then each (list)item becomes a model. All the models are wrapped up in an array list.

Now, when the user clicks on a list item, the underlying model is going to be serialized and sent as IntentExtra to the next Activity (e.g. a deeper sub list).

Answer (score 2):

If you wan't to send complex objects with `putExtra()` they should implement the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) interface.

Comment: I'm using java.io.Serializable according to the exmaple of http://lyle.smu.edu/~coyle/cse7392mobile/handouts/Intent.DataPassing.ZomDroid.pdf Should I favor Parcelable over Serializeable?

Comment: I think you should favor Parcelable if you intend to create a ContentProvider to share your data. And perhaps it's better to send a reference to a really complex object (uri to image instead of sending image using putExtra() )

Comment: I added more information about my app above, so u will see what I am using the intent extras for.